# empty form text filed

Tags: forms, flutter, flutter-text

I'm using a `FormTextField` in a Flutter app

To update a certain column value, the user types in the `FormTextField`, otherwise leaves the field empty.

I tried this code, but it was adding a `null` value to the column, deleting the existing value. I'm not happy with this behavior.

```
      String _getProd5Name() {
           if ((_prod5Controller.text).isNotEmpty == true) {
              _prod5String = _prod5Controller.text;
            } 
             return _prod5String;
           }
```

Is there a way to do it?

I found similar questions, but they are relevant to other languages and their solutions don't solve my case.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
String _getProd5Name() {
    // Actually you don't have to make it private
    // since this is a local variable inside a function
    String _prod5String = variableContainingInitialValue;

    if (_prod5Controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
        _prod5String = _prod5Controller.text;
      }
    return _prod5String;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my advice, since I love wrapping everything on 1 line. You can change the "" part with your result expectation. It's the same with your logic but it's shorter and instead of returning null I make it returning the empty string "". And also (_prod5Controller.text).isNotEmpty == true you can just shorten it to (_prod5Controller.text).isNotEmpty because .isNotEmpty always returning boolean true/false and if-else consuming boolean

```
String _getProd5Name() {
   return ((_prod5Controller.text).isNotEmpty) ? _prod5String = _prod5Controller.text : "";
}
```

Comment: @dwikumiantim...the empty string will delete the existing column value.. It's the same effect as null... I not want both.. I need a way to keep the existing column value in case the user not want update that specific text field.

Comment: the question is do you want to send the existing (unchanged) value to the backend or not?
if you want to you can follow sidrao2006 solution.
it's easy just send them back (the unchanged value) to the backend so you don't have to take these validation